# Create facebook ad for people who like specific group or page (targetting)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I would like to boost a specific post and target people who liked a group or page that I do **not own**.

Can this be done or it's forbidden to prevent spam (or whatever)?

I used targeted advertising to create such group, but I was offered to (in/ex)clude people for my own page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done and there's no problem in doing it. Matter of fact, groups and pages are used as "Topics" when it comes to this, along with other pages and topics.

Lets suppose I have a pet shop and I want to target people who have interests for pets, I could target - `pets, cat, dog, pet community, pet page`. In this context, **pet community** and **pet page** become a Topic, and can be added as a target-public, targeting the people who liked this topic (meaning page or community) as a potential public.

> I could even add - `Google, Facebook` or any other page or company as a target-public if I feel it's in context.

This is also one of the reasons why, when you create a page, you have the option to chose in what section will your page fit, whether it's in - `sports, movies, comedy, entertainment, technology etc...`, to fit in Topics, which will be used later in this concepts, and of course to have more chances to be found in an accurately search, among other things.

Comment: I was referring to a specific page. For example, the page name is SoftGloves and I would like to target those users who liked this page. Can this be done? What do I set and where?

Comment: yes @justanotherguest , you can add SoftGloves as a target so every person who liked SoftGloves will see your Ad. It may not be every person tho, because that will depend on the "amount of people to reach" you define on your Ad definitions.

Comment: Cool, I will try this. I was not sure if this would work.

Comment: This does not work in Audience Insight? There is no column I can enter custom target. All they allows is a predefined entries. In this respect, I cannot view how many people will be targeted. Or you were maybe referring to some other tool.

Comment: yeah, when you promote a post or page this option appears. The "how many people" the post or page will reach, will depend on how much money you spend.

Comment: Ok I will try this although Facebook does not recognize the page names I enter